# Excel 2007 VBA To Pause Macro

Tags: excel, loops, macros, vba

I currently have a macro that reaches out to a directory and pulls some data into my spreadsheet. Originally I just had a button to bring the information in and a button to erase everything but needs have changed and I now need it to automatically run the macro to clear the existing data and then pull new data every hour or so.

Looking through the different ways I could potentially pause the macro is appears that a loop is the best way to go for me because it will allow me to still interact with the spreadsheet while the wait is running.

All that said, here is what I currently have which seems to simply loop through everything without ever pausing at all.

At the end of my macro I use the following

```
Call DelayOneHour 
Call RepActiveTicketsDelete 
Call DelayTwoSeconds
Call RepActiveTicketsDataGrab
```

And here are the loops

```
Sub DelayOneHour()

    Dim NowTick As Long
    Dim EndTick As Long

    NowTick = Now
    EndTick = Now + TimeValue("0:01:00")

    Do Until NowTick >= EndTick
        DoEvents
        NowTick = Now()
    Loop

End Sub

Sub DelayTwoSeconds()

    Dim NowTick As Long
    Dim EndTick As Long

    NowTick = Now
    EndTick = Now + TimeValue("0:01:00")

    Do Until NowTick >= EndTick
        DoEvents
        NowTick = Now()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: What do you mean by "without ever pausing at all"?  I mean, right, technically nothing is paused and run-time is ongoing during that loop, for one hour (or 2 seconds, etc.).  That is probably not ideal though, and a better approach might be to use `Application.OnTime` method instead, which is basically a way to "schedule" a macro to run at a specific time in the future.

Comment: So with the code as it stands rather than pausing for a minute between running RepActiveTicketsDelete and RepActiveTicketsDataGrab is just fires them back and forth on about a 1-2 second interval.

I didnt want to use Application.OnTime because it will make the application unusable while it waits (as far as I could tell in my testing)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "fires them back and forth on about a 1-2 second interval"... I'll post an answer using the `OnTime` method let's see if that helps.

Comment: Did you notice that both of your `Delay` procedures are only using `Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")` which is only a *one second* delay?

Comment: I thought I had them set for 1 minute given their location but even changing the 1 to a 30 has no effect on the behavior

Comment: ahh yes, you're right, 1 minute not 1 second, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd consider `Application.OnTime` as a way to effectively *schedule* a procedure to run at a later time. This frees up the runtime environment (i.e., so you could run other macros from other workbooks during the intervening 1 hour, etc).

Instead of:

```
Call DelayOneHour 
Call RepActiveTicketsDelete 
Call DelayTwoSeconds
Call RepActiveTicketsDataGrab
```

Do this:

```
'Run the specified procedure in one hour:
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:60:00"), "RepActiveTicketsDelete"
Exit Sub
```

Then, at the end of the `RepActiveTicketsDelete` procedure, you scheduled the `RepActiveTicketsDataGrab` procedure:

```
'Run the specified procedure in two seconds:
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "RepActiveTicketsDataGrab"
Exit Sub
```

Comment: This is working to loop through at the correct interval but it appears to be having an affect on some of the forumla's I have running on the sheet. They seem to only calculate when the app is done waiting to run the macro.

Comment: The issue was on my side, not sure what it was but moving to an older version took care if it. Thanks!